# App crashes while setting UITableViewCell controls data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have an app where i m loading data in viewDidLoad as follows

```
 dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
    [self loadProfile];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [tblViewProfile reloadData];

    });
});
```

the app crashes after creating a cell and setting data for the label controls in custom UITableViewCell, the code is as follows

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ProfileViewCell";

    ProfileViewCell *cell = (ProfileViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray * customcellArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ProfileViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for(id customcellObject in customcellArray){
            if([customcellObject isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell = (ProfileViewCell *)customcellObject;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    cell.lblFollowers.text = strFollowers;
    cell.lblFollowing.text = strFollowing;
    cell.lblName.text = strName;
    cell.lblOOTD.text = strOOTD;

    return cell;
}
else
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PostViewCell";


    PostViewCell *cell = (PostViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray * customcellArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"PostViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for(id customcellObject in customcellArray){
            if([customcellObject isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell = (PostViewCell *)customcellObject;
                break;
            }
        }

    }



    return cell;


}

}
```

When I am setting data to cell members here

```
 cell.lblFollowers.text = strFollowers;
    cell.lblFollowing.text = strFollowing;
    cell.lblName.text = strName;
    cell.lblOOTD.text = strOOTD;
```

the very first line above crashes app with bad access error. if i remove that line next line causes the same crash, I am not getting the reason for this crash.

Please help

***Edit***
Did some testing and then figured out that the Bad Exec is being caused by 
strFollowing,strFollowers etc. but I have initialized them not sure where are and why are they getting deallocated.

Comment: Try logging cell and cell.lblFollowers to see if either is nil.

Comment: BTW, you can get rid of those if(cell == nil) clauses if you register your nib, which is the way Apple recommends to do it (using registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake or rather short of knowledge,

While declaring a variable as a property , one needs to access it using 'self' keyword so as to call the setter method , then only the variable is retained else its released, as I was not using self keyword to access these variables they were getting released and causing bad access.

I hope this helps some one else.

Comment: I am glad that you figured this out early else it could be real headache :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Utility method to get Class instance from NibName

```
+ (id)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName ofClass:(Class)objClass 
{
    if (nibName && objClass) 
    {
        NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName 
                                                     owner:nil 
                                                   options:nil];            
        for (id currentObject in objects )
        {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:objClass])
                return currentObject;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Use this in your code like

```
ProfileViewCell *cell = (ProfileViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ProfileViewCell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [Utility loadNibNamed:@"ProfileViewCell" ofClass:[ProfileViewCell class]];

}

PostViewCell *cell = (PostViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PostViewCell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [Utility loadNibNamed:@"PostViewCell" ofClass:[PostViewCell class]];

}
```

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: You think the reason is loading xib ?

Comment: Anyways tried it still crashing on the same line i m sure its not loading of xib

Comment: There may be more reasons. If you are using non ARC then you should check for memory handling, because extra release can cause BAD_ACCESS crash

Comment: Can you share how you allocated strFollowing & strFollowers

Comment: They are normal class members NSString *strFollowers, NSString *strFollowing etc

Comment: if these are ivars please make sure that they are retained while ViewController is alive and released when it is deallocated.

Comment: declared that as a property with retain but still same issue what else i need to do here ? pardon my limited knowledge

Comment: I think i figured out the entire thing